# Por que en el ciclo for no se modifican mis variables?

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles, jcreator

hice una función con la librería swing para llenar una matriz con datos enteros el problema es que la variable de tipo cadena que debería almacenar la matriz para mostrarla en pantalla, no se modifica dentro del ciclo for osea se queda vacía como la declare, y al correr el programa no me pide los datos de entrada que debería pedirme.

```java
    void Ingresar(int f,int c,int x[][],String men)
    {
        String dat="";
        for(int i=0;i<f;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
            {
                dat=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(men+"\nIngresa el dato ["+i+"]["+j+"]");
                x[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(dat);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: En ningun momento muestras los datos, como sabes que no almacenan?, y si lo haces fuera de la funcion que muestras, pues la solucion es simple retorna el array.

Comment: Que es importante menciones como llamas el método Ingresar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando tu pasas una variable a una función, a excepción de que sea un **puntero**, cualquier modificación que sufra dentro de la misma no se reflejará, pues es como clonarla, a esto se le llama **pasar como valor**.

En algunos lenguajes, es tan fácil como pasar la variable **como referencia**, tal que así:

```
void algo(int &x)
```

Añadiendo **&** cualquier modificación sufrida en el interior del método, se reflejará en el exterior.

**En Java esto no es posible**, la única forma sería que la variable estuviera contenida en un objeto.

Al no ser el caso, tienes dos opciones:

**-** Que la variable esté accesible desde el scope de la función:

```
static int x = 0;
public static void Ingresar(int a, int b......) {
    x = 1; // Si hubiera una variable x dentro de la función, para acceder a la exterior harías this.x
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ingresar(a, b....);
    System.out.println(x); // Mostrará 1
}
```

**-** O bien devolver el resultado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    x = Ingresar(x);
    System.out.println(x); // Mostrará 1
}

public static int Ingresar(int x) {
    x = x + 1;
    return x;
}
```

Espero haberte servido de ayuda :)